# Input accents in iTerm with international keyboard

Tags: zsh, iterm2, utf-8, locale

I have an international keyboard where accents are inserted doing

```
ALT+`  e   ==> è
ALT+e  e   ==> é
```

In Terminal.app this works correctly, in iTerm2 it doesn't. I get a bell sound when I press the ALT key combinations. This happens both in vi or emacs mode. I'm on OSX 10.9.3, using zsh, and my locale output is:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

IMPORTANT: I cannot input the characters, but I can see UTF-8 characters without problems in iTerm2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by "international keyboard"? Mine is QWERTZ, and I have an extra key right next to the backspace-button. Pressing it once does not output anything, but pressing the "e" afterwards gives me: é. If I do a shift-press on that key, followed by the "e", I get è.

Furthermore you have two options:

1. Click on "Edit" in the menubar. At the very bottom there should be the option "Special characters". Opening that gives me a list of emoticons. But on the top right of that dialogue theres a little icon, which leads you to a list of further characters. In the category "Latin" you'll find the desired charaters.
2. In the "Keys" section within the preferences of iTerm you can reassign the option, command keys etc. Reassigning your option key might override the default behaviour which leads to the bell.

make sure you have set option key to Normal and not +Esc

[image]

Comment: I have to press ALT+` and then e to get è, it's similar to your case

Comment: btw, this should be a comment, not an answer, since it does not answer the question but only asks for clarifications

Comment: Please notice my rep of 24. I can't comment. I've improved the above to be an answer.